# App not responding/hang without any reason

Tags: xcode, visionkit

Our app load feeds from server
server send us `10 records per page`.

App is working fine but when records greater than `100`
it hang randomly (some time it hang on `10th page` and some time it hang `25th page)` without any crash and error in debug console.

just give us this issue in debug console:

```
[com.apple.VisionKit.processing] Error processing request from MAD on 
result: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "[MADServicePublic] 
Client requests would exceed maximum allowed (MADRequestID 604)" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=[MADServicePublic] Client requests would 
exceed maximum allowed (MADRequestID 604)} request: 
<VKCImageAnalyzerRequest: 0x2830c82d0> requestID: 605 madRequestID: 604 
cancelled: NO
```

Note: I am not using visionkit in app

Memory is not increasing more than `500 MB` and I am testing on `iPhone 12 pro-max`

Comment: *Client requests would exceed maximum allowed* doesn't ring a bell?

Comment: @vadian Can you please explain little bit more. I am just calling API with Alamofire and adding in array and showing in tableview

Comment: It's just a guess. I regard this message as pretty significant. Without knowing the API I would check how many MAD requests are allowed in a certain amount of time.